# filtering category with detach()

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Help me with detach () function.

I figured out how it works, but I need help in applying it, in my case now it deletes all the selected categories, but you need to do the opposite so that all categories except the selected one are deleted. Is it necessary to somehow put everything except the selected one into a class and use detach () or what is better?

**html**

```
<div class="blog-filter">
    <div class="blog-filter_item active js-filter-blog-list" data-filter="all">All</div>
</div>
<div class="blog-filter-container">
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="blog-filter-title">Choose Category</h1>
    <div class="item-wrapper">
        <div class="blog-filter_item active" data-filter="all">All</div>
        @foreach($categories as $category)
        <div class="blog-filter_item" data-filter=".category_{{$category->id}}">{{ $category->title }} ({{ $category->articles_count }})</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="blog-list">
@foreach($articles as $article)
        <div class="blog-article category_{{ $article->blog_category_id }}">
            <h2 class="blog-article__title">{{ $article->title }}</h2>
        </div>
@endforeach
</div>
```

**js**

```
var divs;
    
$('.blog-article').each(function(i){
  $(this).data('initial-index', i);
});

document.querySelectorAll('.blog-filter_item').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document
      .querySelector('.blog-filter_item.active')
      .classList.remove('active');
    el.classList.add('active');

      var dataFilter = $(el).attr('data-filter');

      $(divs).appendTo('.blog-list').each(function(){
        var oldIndex = $(this).data('initial-index');
          $('.blog-article').eq(oldIndex).before(this);
        });
      divs = null;

      if (dataFilter == 'all') {
        $('.blog-article').show();
      }
      else {
        divs = $(dataFilter).detach();
        $('.blog-article').show(); 
      }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
divs = $('.blog-article').not(dataFilter).detach();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.